# css: how to inherit whole class

Tags: css, inheritance

I have "t_data" class defined to customize the look and feel for majority of my tables.

Though, in some cases I need to do an additional tables specializations: let's say I want tables for "customers" and "orders" looking differently.

Default way to inherit styles is to describe css-definitions for both classes into the same block, something like this:

```
table.t_data, table.t_data_order, table.t_data_customer
{
    background-color: #080;
}
```

That way works well till some extend... until I get TOO MANY different definitions.

Right now I have already something like this:

```
table.t_data thead tr th, table.t_data thead tr td, table.t_data tbody tr th,     table.t_data tbody tr td, table.t_data tfoot tr th, table.t_data tfoot tr td,
table.t_group thead tr th, table.t_group thead tr td, table.t_group tbody tr th,     table.t_group tbody tr td, table.t_group tfoot tr th, table.t_group tfoot tr td
{
    border: #333 1px solid;
}
```

In order to do customize t_data to look different for t_data_customer and/or t_data_order I will need to TRIPPLE that block... and there is high risk to miss some elements... I also have more than 10 such blocks for different elements (like background, font, etc.)

**Is there any css or *even non-css* solution for things like this?**

Thank you very much!

P.S. If you don't have any solution but only ideas, don't be shy to share them as well! Any thoughts are welcome

Comment: This is not possible in native CSS, but there are CSS precompilers that offer inheritance and more, e.g. LESS: http://lesscss.org/

Comment: Using HTML elements with multiple classes might help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sadly, you can't do this with CSS. Luckily, you can use CSS precompilers to do this for you (examples: [LESS](http://lesscss.org/) & [Sass](http://sass-lang.com/)). To be more precise, you could use **Mixins** (supported by both languages).

> Mixins allow you to embed all the properties of a class into another
>   class by simply including the class name as one of its properties.
>   It’s just like variables, but for whole classes. Mixins can also
>   behave like functions, and take arguments, as seen in the example
>   below.

```
.rounded-corners (@radius: 5px) {
  -webkit-border-radius: @radius;
  -moz-border-radius: @radius;
  -ms-border-radius: @radius;
  -o-border-radius: @radius;
  border-radius: @radius;
}

#header {
  .rounded-corners;
}
#footer {
  .rounded-corners(10px);
}
```

(Example from LESS). This is something you could do with your `t_data` class.

Comment: Didn't use it yet, but most likely will proceed with LESS - that sounds like a very good idea.

Answer (score 1):

What about adding new common CSS class for your tables and target

```
.common td
.common th {
}
```

Before you add a class to your table you should make sure that the default styling of your table isn't enough e.g.

```
td {
    /* Sensible default for all table cells */
}
```

The next step is to find a class name that's "common" for your tables with alternate styling. The popular framework twitter bootstrap uses "table-bordered" for table with borders, other would argue that it would be better to find a semantic common denominator. But that's up to you.

This is not about semantic or not, but ever since a saw a presentation by Nicole Sullivan, I can't find the presentation but I can find a quote from it:
http://css-tricks.com/semantic-class-names/

> In a presentation by Nicole Sullivan I recently saw at the CSS Summit, she called out some big companies for declaring the exact same color in the CSS files literally thousands of times.

I've been trying to find a meaning for what we're writing in out css files and aiming for large common denominators.

Comment: Am I correctly understand that you suggest to all common stuff into default formatting so that will reduce amount of t_data class required to be reused? That won't really work as I use tables in a lot of scenarios and will need to make sure each class will override the default style. In fact, it is not only about tables.

Comment: It depends from site to site, but I'm looking for creating a sensible default e.g. a table should have more or less the same look and feel over the whole site to keep the design consistent. Then you'll have couple of different tables, hopefully with something common that can be styled using the same class.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of defining many classes, you can use ID and class.

With ID you define the major CSS and with classes you define the differences.

```
<table id="mainstyle" class="variation1"> ...
```

Comment: I often have few tables per page and using ids for formatting doesn't look to attrective